# react native search and scroll to hit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-animated

I need some help implementing a search and scroll to hit in react native. Did a lot of searches and ended up in some dead ends (found some `refs` examples I couldn't get to work).

Tried building this snippet as a kick-off:

https://snack.expo.io/@norfeldt/searching-and-scroll-to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    text: '41'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <TextInput
        style={{height: 60, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, margin: 5, padding:30, color: 'black', }}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />

      <ScrollView >

          {[...Array(100)].map((_, i) => {return <Text style={styles.paragraph} key={i}>{i}</Text>})}

      </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

Any help getting started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps

1. Remember every item's position with `onLayout`.
2. `scrollTo()` position when text input, and only if item found.

### Code

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textinput: {
        borderBottomColor: 'purple',
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 16,
        margin: 10,
    } 
});



export class App extends Component {
    data = [];
    datapos = {};
    scrollref = null;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        /// make 100s example data
        for (var i =0; i<100; ++i)
            this.data.push(i);

        this.state = {
            inputvalue: '0'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput}
                    value={this.state.inputvalue}
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                        this.setState({inputvalue: text});
                        let y = this.datapos[+text];
                        y !== undefined && this.scrollref.scrollTo({ y, animated: true });
                    }}
                />
                <ScrollView
                    ref={(ref) => this.scrollref = ref}
                    >
                    {
                        this.data.map( (data) => (
                            <Text style={styles.text}
                                key={data}
                                onLayout={(layout) => this.datapos[data] = layout.nativeEvent.layout.y}
                                >{data}</Text>
                        ))
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your example also works for elements of different height - https://snack.expo.io/@norfeldt/search-and-scroll-to-hit

Comment: Yes, it's designed to deal with different height of rows. It happened on some contents like Facebook posts, that cannot avoid to have long / short contents to put together. It works out nicely in my own app.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be:

You could start by binding a `ref` of your `<ScrollView/>`.

```
// ScrollView Ref.
<ScrollView ref={(ref) => this['ScrollView'] = ref}>
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

And each of your `<Text/>` components (by `index`).

```
// Text Refs.
<Text ref={(ref) => this[i] = ref} style={styles.paragraph} key={i}>{i}</Text>
```

You could then set a `submit()` `function`.

Said function could find the `ref` equal to `this.state.text` using a `try` `catch` statement for graceful failure in edge cases.

If found; target `x` and `y` offset could be retrieved using [`measure()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback)

`scrollTo()` could then be called to scroll to the target component.

```
// Scroll To Query.
submit = () => {

  try {

    const { text } = this.state // Text.
    const target = this[text] // Target.

    // Locate Target.
    target.measure((framex, framey, width, height, x, y) => {

      // Scroll To Target.
      this.ScrollView.scrollTo({x, y, animated: true})
    })

  } catch (error) {

    return console.log(error)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Tried it out www.snack.expo.io/@norfeldt/searching-and-scroll-to but can't make it work quite. Sometimes it scrolls (to visible components), but mostly nothing happens..

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you typing `numbers`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I highly recommend you to use `FlatList` instead of `ScrollView`. There are a few reasons for this:

1. `FlatList` has much more optimized performance in comparison with ScrollView (in scroll view all items are rendered at once, regardless of the fact if they are visible on screen or not)
2. Moreover, the handling scrolling and rendered items is much simpler in `FlatList`, you do not need to know anything about x, y axis and pixels, you just work with indexes.

in order to have a comprehensive comparison between these two methods you may look at:

http://matthewsessions.com/2017/05/15/optimizing-list-render-performance.html

Now back to your question, as I said I suggest you to use FlatList, then everything will be as simple as a piece of a cake.
You can find modified example of your expo in:

https://snack.expo.io/HkMZS1SGz

The changes that you need to make in your code, include:

1. Instead of ScrollView use, FlatList, so change this:

   `<FlatList
     ref={ref => {this.flatListRef = ref;}}
     data={new Array(100).fill(0).map((item, index) => index)}
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
         {item}
          </Text>
     )}
   />`

If you are not already familiar with `FlatList`, you need to know, the data is added in `data` prop as an array (I added an array of 100 numbers), and the way it is rendered is given to `FlatList` as `renderItem`prop (I added the text with the same styling as you did).

Moreover, note that you do not need to pass ref to `<Text>`, because `FlatList` already knows about items that it contains. You just need to add a ref to the `FlatList` itself:

```
 ref={ref => {this.flatListRef = ref;}}
```

Now when ever you want to make and scrolling, you can simple call `scrollToIndex` method of the `FlatList`, for example write a method called `scrollHandler`:

```
 // Scroll to Query
  scrollHandler = (itemIndex)=>{
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: itemIndex});
  }
```

just pay attention that,`flatListRef` is the name of the ref assigned to the `FlatList`.

now, when you want to perform scroll action, you can simply call this method. Forexample, modify your text input to:

```
<TextInput
        style={{height: 60, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, 
                borderRadius: 10, margin: 5, padding:30, color: 'black', }}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        onSubmitEditing={()=>this.scrollHandler(this.state.text)}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer is really good and spot on to my question. My issue is thought that I have items with different height (know my example didn't) and that it doesn't work - see https://snack.expo.io/@norfeldt/searching-and-scroll-to

Comment: There are a few factors that concern me:
 1- Why should your list contain items of different height? it is a bad UX design practice because, in the small screen of a smartphone, the user does not usually expect such a behavior, it is either a list of specific cards or it is better not to list at all. 
2-If in any case your list contains items of different height, it is better not to use scrollToIndex and scrollToItem, the API of these two methods is still experimental, and have several bugs in complicated cases.
I added a PS to the post discussing this cases.

Comment: I know it bad practice to use different height. But I&#39;m parsing some json content that needs to be formatted differently (and creates different height).

Comment: Tried to take a second look at the FlatList (had performance issues), but reading the docs don't do much to help you out with dynamic content https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/flatlist.html#getitemlayout